# in pyqt6，how to play audio?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I want to play a .mp3 audio file, I have seen the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer.html).
the documentation writes the below code.

```
player = QMediaPlayer()
audioOutput = QAudioOutput()
player.setAudioOutput(audioOutput)
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), self, SLOT(positionChanged(qint64)))
player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/Users/me/Music/coolsong.mp3"))
audioOutput.setVolume(50)
player.play()
```

and below is my code.

```
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.setup_listener()
        audio = QAudioOutput()
        self.player.setAudioOutput(audio)
        filename = '1111.mp3'
        fullpath = QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(filename)
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)
        self.player.setSource(url)
        self.player.play()

        print(self.player.hasAudio())  # true
        print(self.player.isPlaying())  # true
```

I ensure the above two sentences print all print true,
but I did not hear any voice.
What's wrong with my code?
Thanks all.

I have tried to use other .mp3 files and use an absolute path, but no voice appears.

Comment: please don't include your [code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and include it directly as text

Comment: @mikmke Also, for future reference, always try to provide a complete [mre]: your new code is incomplete but your original image it showed that you used a basic python object class, which might could make things work differently in certain cases. Finally, it's quite important to also specify the major version of the toolkits you're using in the tags or at least in the question body: the QtMultimedia framework has changed a lot from Qt5 to Qt6, and while this issue may exists for both versions, you can never be sure about it.

Comment: Also note that the documentation you're linking refers to "Qt for Python" (aka, PySide), but you tagged your question for PyQt, so we cannot be completely sure about which one you're using, as many people consider them the same thing: while PyQt and PySide are conceptually identical, they are not the same thing (and cannot be used together) and there are slight differences between their behavior when dealing with the python objects that wrap Qt objects or how they are eventually destroyed. So, always ensure that you're using the correct tags and be specific about versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try keeping a reference to the `QAudioOutput` object by storing it as a instance attribute, as well as the `QMediaPlayer`.  I think what might be happening is the audio output is being garbage collected after the class constructor is exits.

For example

```
    self.player = QMediaPlayer()
    self.audio = QAudioOutput()
    self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio)
    self.player.setSource(...)
    self.player.play()
```

Comment: Another (and more consistent, Qt-wise) option would be to add the parent argument to the QAudioOutput.

Comment: @musicamante  I didn't know that would work, good suggestion.